# Flutter easy localization Source path does not exist

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to add Spanish to my flutter project with easy_localization i added JSON files of US and ES and added the path to it in runApp function as I try to generate keys with flutter

```
pub run easy_localization:generate
```

```
runApp(EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('es', 'ES')],
      path: 'assets/translations/',
      fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
      child: MyApp()));
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

simply just put the path of the folder where localization files are, in my case.

```
flutter pub run easy_localization:generate --source-dir ./assets/translations
```

Comment: I am using `csv` how to do this?

Answer (score 19):

In case someone get the same error while generating `locale_keys.g.dart` use the below code:

`flutter pub run easy_localization:generate -S assets/translations -f keys -o locale_keys.g.dart`

Answer (score 4):

try the following code:

```
flutter pub run easy_localization:generate -O lib/core/lang -f keys -o locale_keys.g.dart --source-dir ./assets/lang
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure translations file path is given properly in below command, also add
`locale_keys.g.dart` to generate a file with the same name.

```
flutter pub run easy_localization:generate --source-dir ./assets/translations -f keys -o locale_keys.g.dart
```

**Usage:**

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';

LocaleKeys.Name /// Similar way find your keys which declared inside .json file
```

Comment: how can we do this with `.csv` file? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code :

```
flutter pub run easy_localization:generate -s assets/translations
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove /(forwad slash symbol) from path
Like
path:"assets/translations"

that's it.

Comment: String text = textwith_slash.replace("/*","");